# Lightning apps on mobile

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, mobile

When I create a lightning page with Lightning App Builder, I have 2 design options : one for desktop and one for the phone. I customize both for Account object.

[image: Ligthning app builder in Phone mode]

I save the page, activate it as org default for desktop and phones, and as App default for all apps for desktop and phones.
I save again and go back to any account page in my browser, my customized page displays. Perfect !

But when I connect to mobile, either in browser or Salesforce 1 app, no matter what I try (check permissions, double check activation settings, dis/reconnect...) I still have the standard page with 3 tabs (Chatter, Details, Related). No way to have my ligthning page.

[image: Standard record page on phone]

I read here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000UV5SQAW that Salesforce 1 won't use a Ligthning page. If it's true, what is the point of  activing pages as default record pages for mobile ? It makes no sense...

What am I missing ? Please help, it's driving me nuts !

Comment: I can't seem to immediately find the documentation on this... but you may need to enable the [Mobile on Lightning permission](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_general_new_mobile_app_pilot.htm)...

Comment: It does work, thank you so much I'd never have found ! Funny thing my post title was almost the name of the permission I had to turn on :) You should make an answer so I can mark it as best. However is it not insane that there is a complete framework to configure apps for mobile when it's still an experimental feature, without even a notice ? Or did I definitely miss it ?

Comment: Salesforce did seem to put the cart before the horse on this a bit... but I believe the new functionality is slated for GA in the Winter release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emmanuel, as you've confirmed... if you want to use the Lightning Page framework for mobile, you must enable the Mobile on Lightning Permission: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_general_new_mobile_app_pilot.htm.

In case this link goes away... one ultimately needs to add the "Lightning on Mobile" System Permission to the user... either through a Permission Set or Profile.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, it looks like the permission doesn't exist anymore and is not necessary in Winter 20. Didn't find anything in release notes however...

Comment: The permission has been renamed. It's now "New Salesforce Mobile App." Salesforce has added a "New Salesforce Mobile App QuickStart" option in Setup. You can find it near the top of the Setup menu. The release notes have a section entitled "Salesforce App: Welcome to the New Salesforce Mobile App" that provides some additional information.